# How can I find current element on mouseover using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseover, mouseout

How can I get the class name of the current element that is on mouseover? For example
[image]

When a mouse is over from div to **a**, I want to get the class name of a div element. How can I get it using jQuery?

Comment: can you create a fiddle to elaborate on your issue?

Comment: Post your html and what you have so far

Comment: one way, maybe not the best one is to create a style that is assigned at hover, then find for the element that have that style

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/dJgf4/

Comment: @RobertRozas Can you write this as  answer please?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is my version:

```
function handler(ev) {
var target = $(ev.target);
var elId = target.attr('id');
if( target.is(".el") ) {
   alert('The mouse was over'+ elId );
}
}
$(".el").mouseleave(handler);
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/dJgf4/

```js
function handler(ev) {
    var target = $(ev.target);
    var elId = target.attr('id');
    if( target.is(".el") ) {
       alert('The mouse was over'+ elId );
    }
}
$(".el").mouseleave(handler);
```

```css
.el{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin:1px;
    position:relative;
    background:#ccc;   
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hover an element and refresh the page, than move your mouse away.</p>
<div id="element1" class="el"></div>
<div id="element2" class="el"></div>
<div id="element3" class="el"></div>
<div id="element4" class="el"></div>
<div id="element5" class="el"></div>
<div id="element6" class="el"></div>
<div id="element7" class="el"></div>
<div id="element8" class="el"></div>
<div id="element9" class="el"></div>
```

Answer (score 31):

you can give a try to this:

```
window.onmouseover=function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.className);
};
```

Answer (score 11):

Do you want the class name of the div on which the mouseover event occurs?
If that is the case then refer this,

**HTML**

```
<div class="a">aaaaaaaa</div>
<div class="b">bbbbbbbbb</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('mouseover', 'div', function(e) {
    console.log($(e.target).attr('class'));
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pS6Lf/)

I have used mouseover event with target

e.target gives the element on which that event occurs

If you want to get the class name of div after leaving the mouse from it
then use "mouseleave" event instaed of "mouseover"

Answer (score 2):

What most people have neglected is this request from the OP:

`When mouse over div from a`

Meaning you need to know you've hovered from a specific type of element, **not just from any element.**

I made a global var, changing to true on the `mouseleave` of specific elements, in your case an `a` element. Then, inside the hover function you need to check that it's true.

Here's a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dJgf4/41/)

**Edit:** Updated fiddle demo with edge cases when hovering from `a` element not directly onto the `div`.

Answer (score 2):

Get the position of element on mouseover and then get the class name

```
<div id="wrapper">
<a href="#" class="anchorClass">A</a><div class="divClass">DIV</div>
</div>

$('#wrapper').mouseover(function(e) {
    var x = e.clientX, y = e.clientY,
        elementOnMouseOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
        elementClass=$(elementOnMouseOver).attr('class');
    alert(elementClass);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ankur1990/kUyE7/

If you don't want to apply this only on wrapper div but on whole window/document, then you can replace wrapper with window/document

```
 $(window).mouseover(function(e){});
```

Comment: This would give you any element inside `wrapper`, not just the divs in question.

Answer (score 0):

All depending on how you want it. This could also be an option:

#### »[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/mLQfb/)«

With some more detail. This will only show as true after taking the direct path from `a` to `div`. (The tiny white space between `a` and `div`.) As in:

- `a` -> `div` TRUE
- `a` -> `div` -> `white space in between` -> `div` FALSE

#### »[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/wMvC8/)«

Might hold up. This will also show as true if one go to the tiny white space between `a` and `div`, and then go back to `div`. As in:

- `a` -> `div` -> `white space in between` -> `div` TRUE

```
var mode = 0;
$(window).on("mousemove", function(e) {
    if (e.target.className === "d1") {
        mode = 1;   
    } else {
        var cc = e.target.className;
        if (cc !== "d2" && mode) {
            var el = $(".d1"),
                d1 = {
                    x : el.offset().left,
                    y : el.offset().top,
                    w : el.width(),
                    h : el.height()
                },
                c = {
                    x  : e.pageX,
                    y  : e.pageY
                };
            if (c.x >= d1.x + d1.w && c.y >= d1.y && c.y <= d1.y + d1.h)
                mode = 2;
            else
                mode = 0;
        } else if (cc === "d2" && mode) {
            mode = 3;
        }
    }
    $("#status").html("Current: " + (mode == 3 ? "OVER" : "NOT OVER") + " from a" );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

this should work:

define a class in your style sheet:

```
.detectable-div{
    border: white solid 1px;
}

.detectable-div:hover{
    border: red solid 1px;
}
```

then in your js:

```
$('div.detectable-div:hover').mouseover(function () {
    $(this) // this is your object
})
```

Answer (score -1):

From jQuery API

```
 <div class="className">
      <span class="span">move your mouse</span>
    </div>



<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".className").mouseover(function() {
        var n = $(this).attr("class");
        $(".span").html("");
        $(".span").html("The class :"+n);
      });
   </script>
```